# How do I make my links in a csv clickable in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a csv file that loads my data dynamically but for some reason my links are not clickable in the HTML file.

Here is the contents of my csv file:

```
ID,City,Website,ZipCode 
1,Florida,https://www.test.com,33601 
2,Ohio,https://www.test.com,55555 
3,Indiana,https://www.test.com,46032
```

and here is my code I have so far:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" >

 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src='jquery.min.js'> </script>
 <title>Parsing CSV Files</title>
 <script>

    (function($) {

  //$(document).ready(function() {

 'use strict';

  $.ajax({
  url: 'csv_data.csv',
  dataType: 'text',
  }).done(successFunction);

  function successFunction(data) {
  var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
  var table = '<table>';
  for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
  if (singleRow === 0) {
    table += '<thead>';
    table += '<tr>';
  } else {
    table += '<tr>';
  }
  var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
  var a = $('#test').text();
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a;
  for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
    if (singleRow === 0) {
      table += '<th>';
      table += rowCells[rowCell];
      table += '</th>';
    } else if(rowCells[0]==a){
      table += '<td>';
      table += rowCells[rowCell];
      table += '</td>';
    }
  }
  if (singleRow === 0) {
    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
    } else {
    table += '</tr>';
   }
  }
  table += '</tbody>';
  table += '</table>';
  $('body').append(table);
  }

  // });

  })(jQuery);
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <pan id="test">2</span>
  </body>
```

Right now my links are just static text when the data is loaded in the HTML file. How would I render them as clickable based on what I have in my csv file?

Comment: Sounds like OP just wants us to do his homework - I mean come on this is a silly quesition...you know how to create td's but not a link. GOOGLE IT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your last column in an `<a>` tag. Separately for the 3d cell (`rowCell==2`) you need a bit of a different addition:

```
table += '<td><a href="';
table += rowCells[rowCell]; //The actual link
table += '">';
table += rowCells[rowCell]; //What's displayed on screen, could be changed
table += '</a></td>';
```

The second `rowCell` is what is displayed on screen - you may display an edited version of the URL if you wish.

One way to implement this leaving the rest of your code intact is to change:

```
} else if(rowCells[0]==a){
  table += '<td>';
  table += rowCells[rowCell];
  table += '</td>';
}
```

to

```
} else if(rowCells[0]==a) {
     table += '<td>';
     if (rowCell == 2) table += '<a href="'
     table += rowCells[rowCell];     
     if (rowCell == 2) {
         table += '">';   
         table += rowCells[rowCell]; //This can be changed to table += 'click here!';
         table += '</a>';
     }  
     table += '</td>';
}
```

Comment: The link rendering worked. Thank you! One last thing say I want it to say “click here” how would I do that?

Comment: Change the second `rowCells[rowCell]` (the one inside the `if`) to `"click here"`.

Comment: I did that but I want it to pull the link from the csv file where it says “click here”

Comment: Leave the link on the first part, and change the second. I'm not sure what you're doing, but your goal is `'<td><a href="'+rowCells[2]+'>Click here!</a></td>'` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes that’s what I’m trying to do lol. Where it says “click here” that would be a link so when the user clicks on it it would open up the link that corresponds to what’s in the csv file. What do I need to change in my code?

Comment: Sounds like OP just wants us to do his homework - I mean come on this is a silly quesition...youk now how to create td's but not a link.  GOOGLE IT.

Comment: @user3683976 I'm starting to agree with Jon -  I'll give it one last shot - I gave you the **exact** piece of code to get what you want. I expect a minimal effort from you to understand it, and make it work.

Comment: @kabanus - stop feeding it...you are only hurting yourself.

Comment: Got it to work. Should of used google like you said! LOL. Hanks for the help guys!